# jasmine thorw ERROR: 'NG0303: Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.'

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

This is my html code.

```
<div class="container" echarts [options]="Option"></div>
```

When i run the testcase,throwing following error.
[image]

**Solution1**

[image]

Above solution not recommencement.

Do we have any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import used modules:

```js
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [NgxEchartsModule],
});
```